# Open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ containing $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: lebesgue-measure, real-numbers

I am trying to understand some properties of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ which contain rational numbers; more precisely I am thinking about their measure. It is easy to show that there are such open subsets with finite measure, and even arbitrarily small measure. Let $\epsilon >0$ be a real number and let $(p_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$. Then we can consider the set:
$$
A=\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} (p_n-\epsilon/2^n,p_n+\epsilon/2^n)
$$
This is open and contains rational numbers. Its measure is less than the sum of measures of the intervals in the union. This sum is eqaul to $4\epsilon$ so we can make the measure of such an open subset arbitrarily small.

This is where I am starting to struggle. Any open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is the union of countably many disjoint intervals. Since the rational numbers are dense in $\mathbb{R}$ the complement of $A$ cannot contain any interval as a subset. In my understanding (or intuition), this implies that when we write $A$ as a countable union of disjoint open intervals, the adjacent open intervals are almost touching each other i.e. their distance to each other is zero. Intuitively, this would imply that the complement of $A$ is countable as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. (I mean that only the endpoints of the open intervals are not contained in $A$.)

So, when I think geometrically(?) I feel that an open set containing rationals should have infinite measure. I am aware that this is not the case as $A$ has finite measure. Can anybody point out where I am wrong or how should I think about these sets?

Comment: What this example (among others) shows is that our (untrained) intuition fails pretty badly, and that the two concepts of "size" as described in topology and in measure theory aren't really compatible. Explicitly, the notion of density in topology describes sets which are "large" in terms of a topological sense. However, this doesn't coincide with the notion of size in terms of measure theory.

Comment: One thing to note is that in such an open covering, there are no "adjacent open intervals".  Rather, given any open set in your covering, there exist intervals arbitrarily close to it on either side.  In fact you could make an analogous argument  (with the same flaw) without even introducing the open covering:  there are countably many rationals, and at most one irrational "between any two consecutive rationals", so there should only be countably many irrationals.  But in fact there are uncountably many; they correspond to Dedekind cuts rather than consecutive pairs of rationals.

Comment: @RaviFernando Yeah, the similarity with the Dedekind cuts makes sense. Thanks.